# bcrypt.compare cannot set response headers in nextjs

Tags: javascript, express, bcrypt, next.js

I can't seem to get the correct response headers when my code enters bcrypt.compare. I thought it was a cors issue at first but I still get the correct response if I entered the wrong and "user does not exist" is displayed.

Here's my api server side code in express

```html
router.post("/api/signIn", (req, res) => {
  const { user, password } = req.body;
  const queryString = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?";
  db.query(queryString, [user])
    .then(result => {
      if (result.length > 0) {
        const hash = result[0].password;

        //here bcrypt.compare works server side or with cURL but won't set the response headers in the browser

        bcrypt
          .compare(password, hash)
          .then(same => {
            if (same === true) {
              console.log("correct password");
              res.status(200).json({
                code: 200,
                message: "correct password"
              });
            } else {
              res.status(401).json({
                code: 401,
                message: "incorrect password"
              });
            }
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      } else {

      //this one works though and i can get the response in the browser so it can't be a cors issue

        console.log("user does not exist");
        res.status(200).json({
          code: 401,
          message: "User does not exist"
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("error" + err.message);
    });
});
```

and this is the test function i use in react

```html
  const signIn = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/signIn", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        user: userName,
        password: password
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => alert(response.code + response.message))
      .catch(err => alert(err));
  };
```

so if i entered the wrong username that is not in the database, the alert function would show (code401User does not exist) but if i entered the correct user bcrypt.compare() doesn't seem to set the response for both correct and incorrect passwords and i would get (TypeError: failed to fetch). testing the api in cURL works though.

Comment: Can you please check browser's console for more details about the error, like CORS?

Comment: @SureshPrajapati is this the one? the user:sad and password:sad exist in the database so it should return message: "correct password"

Request URL: http://localhost:5000/api/signIn
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Provisional headers are shown
Content-Type: application/json
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:3000/signin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Mobile Safari/537.36
{user: "sad", password: "sad"}
password: "sad"
user: "sad"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, I forgot to put event.preventDefault() on the fetch function.